# Floating "Tip" box using wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm trying to make a floating "Tip" box. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{tip}[1][3cm]
    {\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{#1}\begin{framed}Tip:\\}
    {\end{framed}\end{wrapfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tip}
Hello this is a test
\end{tip}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Right now it looks like this:
[image: output]

And this is what I want:

[image: wanted]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a `\newcommand` instead of a `\newenvironment`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \newcommand{\tip}[2][3cm]
        {\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{#1}
        \begin{framed}
        Tip:\\ #2
        \end{framed}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        }

    \begin{document}
    \tip {Hello this is a test}
    \lipsum[1]
    \tip[5cm]{Hello this a wider box}
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i cant reproduce your result.  first `\tip` command is correct placed, but it overwrite paragraph text. the second one is below of text. i use recent `miktex`

Comment: @Zarko I have rechecked the code and its output first on overleaf and second with Texlive 2018. For me it's ok!

Comment: than i can only concluded that within `mitex` is something different as in `texlive` or in `overleaf`` ...

Comment: @zarko I realy don't know what to conclude! I don't use miketex.

Comment: The reason why a command works and an environment not is that the `wrapfigure` must not be included into a group, which is added by the environment. This is stated in the manual. Hafids solution works for me with TeXLive 2018. I don't think MikTeX will act any different. The underlying TeX engine is the same!